# Cacert issue with multiple aliases / certificates - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, exception, java-8, keystore

I am looking for ways to remove all aliases and certificates, and have a fresh start. 
I tried searching for the **keystore** file but I am not able to find it. 
I have no idea about the result of deleting 'cacerts' file in my java home.

Currently I am getting this exception: 
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem

I am using Java 8.

I will appreciate your help. Thanks !

Comment: What are you trying to do that is causing that exception?

Comment: Please add the corresponding code snippet where the exception happens.